# Get network usage from specific date on terminal

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, vnstat

On `vnstat` I can get the month, day, hour or top 10 days network usage. Is there anyway that I can get the network usage from specific date on the terminal? by vnstat or another tool?

Edit:

I want to have the usage from specific date to the current date or between two dates not only a specific date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vnStat supports date and time range specific queries for all list outputs starting from version 2.0 (currently available as beta). That version also allows free configuration of data retention durations so there's no more hardcoded 30 day limit for daily data. See the [change notes](https://github.com/vergoh/vnstat/blob/master/CHANGES) and the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vergoh/vnstat/) for more details.

```
$ vnstat --days --begin 2018-04-02 --end 2018-04-06

 em1  /  daily

      day        rx      |     tx      |    total
-------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------
 2018-04-02      4.88 GB |     1.95 GB |     6.83 GB  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%:::::::
 2018-04-03      3.56 GB |     1.09 GB |     4.66 GB  %%%%%%%%%%%%::::
 2018-04-04      3.91 GB |     2.07 GB |     5.99 GB  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%:::::::
 2018-04-05      2.61 GB |     1.63 GB |     4.24 GB  %%%%%%%%%:::::
 2018-04-06      3.29 GB |     1.43 GB |     4.72 GB  %%%%%%%%%%%:::::
-------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------
  sum of 5      18.25 GB |     8.17 GB |    26.43 GB
```

Comment: Even though I have my own answer +1 to yours for updating us. Thank you. I see why you didn't use `2018-05-02` and `2018-05-06` as parameters instead of `2018-04-02` and `2018-04-06`. It's because the day history only increases from 30 days to 60 days?

Comment: I currently have the configuration set at 60 days so it would be possible to go right now back to `2018-03-07`. I used `2018-04-02` - `2018-04-06` mainly to show that the 30 day limit isn't there anymore and to limit the output to few entries. That 60 days isn't hardcoded either and can be changed at any time for the configuration file. It's even possible to disable the cleanup of old data altogether if needed.

Comment: Apologies I just noticed you are the `vnstat` author and/or maintainer. Congrats on a great package that's a dailiy staple in many lives!

Comment: Thanks for adding this feature. This solution seems much cleaner.

Comment: I've just posted another question you might be interested in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035141/one-vnstat-database-for-multiple-ubuntus

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code below into a file. I'm using `~/bin/vnstat-hist.sh`. After saving the file mark it as executable using:

```bash
chmod a+x ~/bin/vnstat.sh
```

To run the script call it with the parameter for number of days. For example for today use `vnstat-hist.sh 1`. For last five days (including today) use:

```bash
$ vnstat-hist.sh 5
vnstat -d 5 day summary
     2018-04-27     6.21 GiB |    1.83 GiB |    8.04 GiB |  780.45 kbit/s
     2018-04-28     5.97 GiB |    1.05 GiB |    7.02 GiB |  681.20 kbit/s
     2018-04-29     8.27 GiB |    1.47 GiB |    9.74 GiB |  945.40 kbit/s
     2018-04-30     4.09 GiB |    1.35 GiB |    5.44 GiB |  527.97 kbit/s
     2018-05-01     1.36 GiB |    1.13 GiB |    2.49 GiB |  315.40 kbit/s
Total:32.73
```

### `vnstat-hist.sh` Bash script

Note this program can be shorter but hopefully the design is easier to follow for novices.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: vnstat-hist.sh
# PATH: $HOME/bin
# DESC: Written for AU Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030345/get-network-usage-from-specific-date-on-terminal/1030399?noredirect=1#comment1675801_1030399
#       Get total vnStat bytes from x days ago to today.
#       Parameter 1 = number of days: 1= today, 2= yesterday + today, etc.

# DATE: May 1, 2018.

re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "Error: Parameter 1 must be number of days" >&2; exit 1
fi

# Get body of vnstat -d into file, ie strip headings and total lines
# First get count of all lines, then delete 2 total lines & 5 heading lines

vnstat -d > /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt
NumLines=$(cat /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt | wc -l)
NumLines=$(( NumLines - 2))
cat /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt | head -n $NumLines > /tmp/vnstat-hist2.txt
NumLines=$(( NumLines - 5))
cat /tmp/vnstat-hist2.txt | tail -n $NumLines > /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt

MaxDays=$(cat /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt | wc -l)

DayCount="$1"
(( $DayCount > $MaxDays )) && DayCount=$MaxDays
cat /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt | tail -n $DayCount  > /tmp/vnstat-hist2.txt
echo "vnstat -d $DayCount day summary"
awk '{sum+=$8;} END { print "Total:" sum }1' /tmp/vnstat-hist2.txt

# Clean up temp files
rm -f /tmp/vnstat-hist.txt
rm -f /tmp/vnstat-hist2.txt

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to get network usage `on` specific date, I want to get network usage `from` specific date to the current date (now).

Comment: Is the date more than 30 days in the past? If so the records may have to be logged to a history file using `cron` each month.

Comment: Yes. It's from the past 30 days.

Comment: @ICE I've modified the answer with a little script to sum up the number of days.

Comment: @ICE You're welcome. I enjoyed learning some new things putting it together.

Comment: The solution that @TeemuToivola posted here is much cleaner.  I gave the accepted answer to that answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ICE I agree 100%. Unfortunately I'm using an older version of `vnStat` in Ubuntu 16.04 so that option wasn't available when I wrote my answer.